# How to disable radio input with certain values when choosing radio input with the same value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how can disable radio button with name "least1" if i checked radio with name "most1" with same value

```
 <form action="{{route('questionnaire.action')}}" name="QuestionnaireForm" method="post" id="questionnaireEnglishForm">
    <input type="radio" name="most1" value="Trusting & believing in others">

    <input type="radio" name="least1" value="Trusting & believing in others">

    <input type="radio" name="most1" value="Satisfied, easy to please">

    <input type="radio" name="least1" value="Satisfied, easy to please">

    <input type="radio" name="most1" value="Clear">

    <input type="radio" name="least1" value="Clear">

    <input type="radio" name="most1" value="Calm & Peaceful">

    <input type="radio" name="least1" value="Calm & Peaceful">

    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>In Jquery</sup>

<sup>**[1]**</sup> You can use `change` event for `most1`

<sup>**[2]**</sup> Use`.filter()` to filter `least1` by value

<sup>**[3]**</sup> Use `.prop('disabled' , true/false)` to on/off the disabled property

<sup>**[4]**</sup> You may need `.prop('checked' , false)` to uncheck the `least1` if it was checked

```js
$('input[name="most1"]').on('change' , function(){
  var GetValue = $(this).val();
  $('[name="least1"]').prop('disabled' , false).filter(function(){
    return $(this).val() == GetValue;
  }).prop('disabled' , true).prop('checked' , false);
});

var i = 12;
console.log('[name="least' + i + '"]');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="{{route('questionnaire.action')}}" name="QuestionnaireForm" method="post" id="questionnaireEnglishForm">
  <input type="radio" name="most1" value="Trusting & believing in others">

  <input type="radio" name="least1" value="Trusting & believing in others">

  <input type="radio" name="most1" value="Satisfied, easy to please">

  <input type="radio" name="least1" value="Satisfied, easy to please">

  <input type="radio" name="most1" value="Clear">

  <input type="radio" name="least1" value="Clear">

  <input type="radio" name="most1" value="Calm & Peaceful">

  <input type="radio" name="least1" value="Calm & Peaceful">

</form>
```

To concatenate the string in javascript  `$('[name="least' +  i + '"]')` .. You can see the snippet above

Comment: if i can ask about how add variable in input name $('[name="least1"]') 
like that $('[name="least+i+"]') it is not working with me if you can help me .
thank you

Comment: Answer updated ya @AhmedTarek .. I'm here if you need any help ;)